# Lightning Network scaling alternatives?

Tags: scalability, lightning-network

I'm really looking forward to the Lightning Network and all the efforts being put in by Blockchain.info, Blockstream, and others. But I was wondering if there aren't other options for decentralised scaling besides LN?

In particular, are there are other decentralised+offchain scaling models that have been suggested beside hub-and-spoke?

Comment: Channel Factories is a recently proposed scaling technology - a  layer between bitcoin and lightning network https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/what-are-channel-factories-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: I’m working on one but it’s (off-topic here because) not proof-of-work (thus not about Bitcoin), because [proof-of-work can never scale transaction volume _securely_](https://steemit.com/blockchain-scaling/@anonymint/lightning-networks-must-fail-if-it-succeeds).

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/63375/5406

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The obvious one would be side chains, the idea being that the transactions on the side chain would be off the main chain. Most other scaling solutions are either on-chain or centralized. For example, segwit and block size increases are on-chain and using a service like coinbase to move coins off-chain are clearly centralized.

Comment: Any off chain solutions in the works currently? I would like to see some competition to LN, since LN nodes are said to have to register within the US.

Comment: The simplest off chain solution is to have a 2of2 multi-sig wallet with someone who does not share their key with you (and vice versa). Both of you can add to this multi-sig wallet but if you wanted to move the funds out of it, the signature of both you and the other party would be required.

Practical example: one has bitcoin but wants to regularly sell little parts to the other side without paying any on-chain fees. All you need is a shared knowledge of how much belongs to each one. For example a PrivateBin bin could be used for that.

Comment: The more I read and learn about ln, the more I want to see other solutions.