# Plan to decrease the fees

Tags: transaction-fees

Is there a future plan to make the fees lower ? Will BTC block size increase after the 5G being rolled out in the world ? We could really use a Little bigger block while also developing lighting network . Please don't close this and let's have a conversation.

Comment: related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/36085/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/63375/5406

Comment: 5G bandwidth only addresses one part of the issue with larger blocks. The CPU workload involved in verifying signatures is another bottleneck that is perhaps more pertinent looking forward.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a future plan to make the fees lower ?

Fees is decided by users and will work the same way. Transactions are prioritized based on fee rate by miners.

> Will BTC block size increase

It's already increased after segwit (August 2017)

[What's the blocksize limit after segwit and how do legacy nodes deal with segwit transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/98810/whats-the-blocksize-limit-after-segwit-and-how-do-legacy-nodes-deal-with-segwit/)

> We could really use a Little bigger block while also developing lighting network

As I mentioned above, blocksize is increased and it's not size anymore but weight.

A major problem with simple approaches to increasing the Bitcoin blocksize is that for certain transactions, signature-hashing scales quadratically rather than linearly.

https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/01/26/segwit-benefits/

[image]

Comment: How about a little increase just to make it easier for onchain? A lot people could agree a little increase in block is not that bad ? Do you agree ?

Comment: How do we define "a little" and how would that guarantee anything about on chain fees? As I said above fees is decided by users. If enough transactions are willing to use 50 sat/vByte fee rate on any given day, your transaction with less fee rate will remain less prioritized by miners. Also Segwit % and RBF % is very low, you should be asking wallets and exchanges to use Bitcoin in a better way instead of expecting blocksize increase every few months/years.

Comment: Could the Bitcoin blockchain support 7.7 billion people , 42% of them earn less than 5 dollars a day

Comment: I am not anti small block , I am just curious did not wanted to offend anybody

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63375/what-is-the-difference-between-on-chain-scaling-and-off-chain-scaling/